# [C++]: error C2440: 'static_cast': cannot convert from '_atl_event_classtype *'

Tags: c++, atl

Перестал компилироваться код на строке SINK_ENTRY_INFO:

```
BEGIN_SINK_MAP(ControlEvents)       
    SINK_ENTRY_INFO(0, *EventType, DISPID_Control_OnTimer, EVENT_OnTimer, EVENT_INFO_OnTimer())
END_SINK_MAP()
```

после установки VS2015 Update 3 (хотя возможно и сам где то ошибся):

```
error C2440: 'static_cast': cannot convert from '_atl_event_classtype *' to 'ATL::_IDispEventLocator<0,DIID__IControlEvents> *'
```

где параметры определены:

```
template<const IID* EventType>
class ControlEvents : public IDispEventImpl<...>

#define DISPID_Control_OnTimer 1

HRESULT __stdcall EVENT_OnTimer(IControl* sender, ITimerEvent* timer_event);

static _ATL_FUNC_INFO* EVENT_INFO_OnTimer()
{
    static _ATL_FUNC_INFO _EVENT_INFO_OnTimer = {CC_STDCALL, VT_EMPTY, 2, {VT_UNKNOWN, VT_UNKNOWN} };
    return &_EVENT_INFO_OnTimer;
}
```

Сам код из **atlcom.h** выглядит так:

```
#define BEGIN_SINK_MAP(_class)\
typedef _class _GetSinkMapFinder;\
static const ATL::_ATL_EVENT_ENTRY<_class>* _GetSinkMap()\
{\
    PTM_WARNING_DISABLE \
    typedef _class _atl_event_classtype;\
    static const ATL::_ATL_EVENT_ENTRY<_class> map[] = {
#define SINK_ENTRY_INFO(id, iid, dispid, fn, info) {id, &iid, (int)(INT_PTR)(static_cast<ATL::_IDispEventLocator<id, &iid>*>((_atl_event_classtype*)8))-8, dispid, (void (__stdcall _atl_event_classtype::*)())fn, info},
#define SINK_ENTRY_EX(id, iid, dispid, fn) SINK_ENTRY_INFO(id, iid, dispid, fn, NULL)
#define SINK_ENTRY(id, dispid, fn) SINK_ENTRY_EX(id, IID_NULL, dispid, fn)
#define END_SINK_MAP() \
{0, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, NULL} }; return map;\
PTM_WARNING_RESTORE \
}
```

Действительно внутри ATL есть строка вида:

```
static_cast<ATL::_IDispEventLocator<id, &iid>*>((_atl_event_classtype*)8))-8, dispid, (void (__stdcall _atl_event_classtype::*)())fn, info},
```

Как исправить ошибку компиляции?

Answer (score 1):

Убрал в atlcom.h файле static_cast:

```
#define SINK_ENTRY_INFO(id, iid, dispid, fn, info) {id, &iid, (int)(INT_PTR)((_atl_event_classtype*)8)-8, dispid, (void (__stdcall _atl_event_classtype::*)())fn, info},
```

В итоге программа скомпилировалась и даже работает без ошибок.

Наиболее вероятно что VS2015 Update 3 содержит ошибку в самом С++ компиляторе, потому что причин не компилировать код (который до обновления компилировался без ошибок) я не увидел.